# Issue in "YYYY" NSDateFormatter for leap year

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

Here is the code I used to change the date format.

```
        NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [formatter setDateFormat: @"YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm"];
        NSString *endDate = [formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
```

----------Output---------------

(lldb) po [NSDate date]
2015-12-27 05:24:18 +0000

(lldb) po endDate
2016-12-27 11:09

This issue was fixed when I used @"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm" but I did not understand why a whole year is changed when week based year is used. This issue also occurs for date Dec (27-31) 2020.

Comment: Because the last days of a year can belong to the first week of the next year.

Comment: It would be ok if it had shown first week of the next year, but it is showing last month and last date. i.e no change in date. Please take a look at output in question.